# What's the difference between ‘global-set-key "\M-…’ and ‘define-key esc-map "…’?

Tags: key-bindings, prefix-keys

Same for `global-set-key "\C-x …` and `define-key ctl-x-map "…`.

I prefer `(global-set-key (kbd "M-KEYS") #'COMMAND)` because it's more readable, but I would like to know if the two kinds of binding -- expliciting the `Meta` key and using the `ctl-x-map` -- differ in some ways.

Comment: (global-set-key (kbd "C-c M-v") #'command)

Comment: @RichieHH: Please post that as an answer (but with `C-x`, not `C-c`, since the former is the OP example). And consider elaborating a bit, to make the difference clear. And please also add a corrected string version, i.e., without `kbd`. Bonus points for pointing to the manual node that explains this. ;-)

Comment: I'm pretty sure the effect of these functions is identical, i.e., `(global-set-key "\C-x a" 'forward-line)` and `(define-key ctl-x-map "a" 'forward-line)` do exactly the same thing. However, I can't find a definitive confirmation of this in the Emacs manual or the Elisp manual.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The potential difference is that `esc-map` and `ctl-x-map` can be bound to keys other than `ESC` and `C-x`.

If you don't do that, then the two approaches are effectively the same.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using function `kbd`, which is described [here](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Key-Sequences.html).

`(global-set-key (kbd "C-x M-v") #'command)`

Comment: I had tried using `kbd` but I must have made some mistake because I got an error. I have removed that part from the question. Anyway, that was just a -- wrong -- example of a difference, but my question is more about the difference between the two ways of binding a key, in general, than the specific issue with `C-x M-v`. Thanks for the tip and sorry if I wasn't clear.